# Whats happening this code. Anagram as a substring in a string

Tags: python, algorithm, anagram

I found this question posted on here, but couldn't comment or ask a question, so I am creating a new question.

The original post stated the following:

```
t = "abd"
s = "abdc"
```

s trivially contains t. However, when you sort them, you get the strings abd and abcd, and the in comparison fails. The sorting gets other letters in the way.

Instead, you need to step through s in chunks the size of t.

```
t_len = len(t)
s_len = len(s)
t_sort = sorted(t)
for start in range(s_len - t_len + 1):
   chunk = s[start:start+t_len]
   if t_sort == sorted(chunk):
   # SUCCESS!!
```

In the for loop why are they taking S-len then subtracting t_len?  Why are they adding 1 at the end?

Comment: Because you can only have at most `s_len - t_len + 1` substrings within `s` with a length of `t_len`. To summarize, on a 4 character string, you can have up to 2 substrings of 3 character strings each. That is, the first 3 characters and the last 3 characters, `abd` and `bdc`.

Comment: That is essentially creating a window of size (len(t)) which then you slide over len(s). i.e. check all contiguous substrings of length len(t) in s. In this example 2 substrings of length 3.

Comment: Thank you alvits  that helped to clarify things.

Comment: Thank you d_void your explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**alvits** and **d_void** already explained the value of `start`; I won't repeat that.

I strongly recommend that you learn some basic trace debugging.  Insert some useful **print** statements to follow the execution.  For instance:

Code:

```
t = "goal"
s = "catalogue"

t_len = len(t)
s_len = len(s)
t_sort = sorted(t)
print "lengths & sorted", t_len, s_len, t_sort

for start in range(s_len - t_len + 1):
   chunk = s[start:start+t_len]
   print "LOOP start=", start, "\tchunk=", chunk, sorted(chunk)
   if t_sort == sorted(chunk):
      print "success"
```

Output:

```
lengths & sorted 4 9 ['a', 'g', 'l', 'o']
LOOP start= 0   chunk= cata ['a', 'a', 'c', 't']
LOOP start= 1   chunk= atal ['a', 'a', 'l', 't']
LOOP start= 2   chunk= talo ['a', 'l', 'o', 't']
LOOP start= 3   chunk= alog ['a', 'g', 'l', 'o']
success
LOOP start= 4   chunk= logu ['g', 'l', 'o', 'u']
LOOP start= 5   chunk= ogue ['e', 'g', 'o', 'u']
```

Does that help illustrate what's happening in the loop?

Comment: You completely misunderstood the question. The OP was asking why `start` used such a range. You didn't even explain anything. You just gave a suggestion. This is not an answer. This belongs in a comment.

Comment: You already explained the value of `start`; I should reference that.  Unfortunately, this can't go into a comment, as it will not format code and output.

Comment: hey Prune thank you for your example regarding print statements.  However, you misunderstood the question that was being asked.